# Reading Scanner input

Tags: c#, .net, barcode

Can anybody please help me in writing C# Code to read the input read by barcode scanner...like the Scanner to read Flight tickets.

Please provide a Step-by-step process.

Answer (score 3):

It's going to depend on the manufacturer of the device. You'd be best off looking to the manufacturer for some API documentation and example code. See this [channel9 thread for some links and some more info](http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/69898-Barcode-in-NET/?CommentID=69977).

Answer (score 0):

Usually barcode scanners behave like a keyboard : when you read a barcode, it just sends the code as if you had typed it on the keyboard. If your scanner works like that, there is nothing specific to do about it. You just need to have a focused textbox that will receive the input from the scanner